# Countable product of Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H_1, H_2, \ldots $ be a countable set of Hilbert spaces. Let $H\subset \prod_k H_k$ be the set where

$$\|x\|^2 = \sum_k \|x_k\|^2_{H_k} < \infty.$$

Show that $H$ is a Hilbert space.

---

It is very easy to see that a Cauchy sequence in $H$ converges element-wise to an element $x^*$. But how would one show that this element is in $H$, i.e. that $\|x\|^2 < \infty$?

Comment: Can you do the special case $H_{n} = \mathbb{R}$ for all $n$? What you get is the usual space $\ell^2$ and the argument for the general case is exactly the same.

Comment: And your final result is called the "orthogonal direct sum" of the Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Of course another part of the proof that $H$ is a Hilbert space is writing down an inner product corresponding to this norm.

Comment: or verifying the parallelogram identity.